# Ramanujan-Nagell and Pell’s equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In my study of Pell’s equation $(x(d))^2-d(y(d))^2=1$ (eq.1),  I looked at the family of equations where $d=2^n-3$ to which 61 belongs. (This was really a study of d=61 in equation 1.)

In some cases, lower solutions to can be generated by solving the companion equation $(x(d))^2-d(y(d))^2=-1$ (eq.2). I thus studied eq. 2 for the sequence $d=2^n-3$ , and noted that y(d) was simply equal to the previous d, that is  $2^{(n-1)}-3$, and that this occurred for some n, e.g. n= 3, 4, 5, and 7.

The general formulation for such an occurrence is 
$x^2- (2^n-3)*(2^{(n-1)}-3)^2=-1$   requiring that
$x^2= (2^n-3)*(2^{(n-1)}-3)^2-1$  (eq.3), and therefore that
$(2^n-3)*(2^{(n-1)}-3)^2-1$ must be the square of a natural number.

After some rearrangement (and credit to Wolfram Alpha) we have 
$(2^n-3)*(2^(n-1)-3)^2-1 = 1/4 (-7+2^n) (-4+2^n)^2$, i.e. it is required that 
$2^n-7$ is a perfect square, i.e. $2^n-7=x^2$. This is the Ramanujan-Nagell equation, conjectured by Ramanujan (that solutions exist for 3, 4, 5, 7 and 15 only), proposed independently in 1943 by Wilhelm Ljunggren, and proved in 1948 by Trygve Nagell, (Wikipedia, the Ramanujan-Nagell equation).

I was now thinking that this interesting discovery might perhaps help to provide a separate version of Nagell’s proof, giving the special environment of Pell’s equation (not that I have any information of Nagell’s proof but I don’t think he used Pell’s equation). 
The approach would be that $y(d) = y(2^n-3)$ is much higher than the expected $2^{(n-1)}-3$

For n=10, we have $x^2-509y^2=-1$ with y= 17540333253 this is obviously much higher than 253 which would be expected if eq.3 were valid for all n. Obviously one would have to prove something much more difficult, namely that this is the case for all n except 3, 4, 5, 7 and 15.

What do you think of that?

Comment: It seems to me that the first thing you'd do with the Pell equation is exactly what you did, that is, reduce it to Ramanujan-Nagell. I'm skeptical of any significantly different approach to the Pellian.

Comment: So there is nothing new under the sun. That is how my investigations usually end.